# Why do linked questions added in comments appear in the list with delay?

Tags: support, linked-questions

Original post - see below for the edited version:

I've recently noticed that some questions for which links were added in comments did not appear in the list on the right.

Is this a bug or was the behavior of the list of linked questions changed intentionally? Or is there some delay before the linked question appears? (I did not notice any such delay in the past. IIRC after adding a link in an answer or a comment, after refreshing the page, the link was already in the list of linked questions.)

I did not find anything in recently asked questions [tagged linked-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-questions?sort=active&pagesize=15) at meta.SO. The [tag-wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/linked-questions/info) still says that the linked questions *come from questions that users have linked in the question, their answers, or in comments.*

Some examples:

- I've noticed this in the question [What do $\gg$ and $\ll$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232143/what-do-gg-and-ll-mean) - the question linked in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232143/what-do-gg-and-ll-mean#comment516443_232143) is not shown in the list. (At least not at this moment. The comment was added 20 mins ago.)

If I stumble upon more examples, I'll add them here.

---

**EDIT:** When I've checked the question now (2 hours after the comment was added), the question is in the list. So now my question is basically why is there the delay between adding a comment and adding link to a list. (I wonder whether someone can confirm that this used to be immediate.)

Comment: It is now shown in the list. If anything I expect there to be a small delay. Just like badge awarding and such.

Comment: @Willie Thanks for the reply. I've just noticed this too and edited my question accordingly. IIRC this used to be almost immediate, so it surprised me.

Comment: Now in a different question the links appeared within 5 minutes (which is quite good compared with the question I mentioned in the post, where after 40 minutes the links were still missing).

Comment: until an official answer is available, just pretend that the internet tubes were clogged for a while, then the plumber came along...

Comment: Today everything works again in the way as it used to. I've posted some comments containing links here at meta. Right after posting the comments I refreshed the page and the questions were already in the list of related questions.